# Swift error: unrecognized selector sent to instance along with unknown method / function

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new to swift and i have no idea why the app is terminating. I'm using a class function to save data to the persistent store. I also don't have a function called setYearOfBirth. can someone please explain what is going on

Here is the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[User setYearOfBirth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000462a40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e01f12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d213f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0a0024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfa1f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfa1958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Vings                               0x000000010a7fa081 _T05Vings7SetUpVCC9buildUserAA0F0CyF + 833
    6   Vings                               0x000000010a7fb101 _T05Vings7SetUpVCC14saveBtnPressedyypF + 2177
    7   Vings                               0x000000010a7fb648 _T05Vings7SetUpVCC14saveBtnPressedyypFTo + 72
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ebb1972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ed30c3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ed30f59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ed2fe86 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f1a1bad _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5560
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f19ba4d _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1506
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f19b41f -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010f19a4cb -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 288
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ec28f14 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4102
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ebcc365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010f518a1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010f51b672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfc2101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e061f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfa6a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfa5fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dfa5889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001132289c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010ebb05d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  Vings                               0x000000010a7f0ea7 main + 55
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001118bcd81 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the code:

```
class userAction{
    private class func save(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> (), user: User){
        do{
            try managedContext.save()
            completion(true)
        }catch{
            debugPrint("could not save \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

The following is in a view controller class:

```
func buildUser() -> User{
    let user = User(context: managedContext)
    user.yearOfBirth = Int32(ageTxtField.text!)!
    user.wage = Double(wageTxtField.text!)!
    user.gender = userGender.rawValue
    user.hoursWorked = Int32(hoursWorkedTxtField.text!)!
    user.savingsAmount = 0.001
    return user
}

@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if(ageTxtField.text != "") && (wageTxtField.text != "") && (userGender != .blank) && (hoursWorkedTxtField.text != ""){
        let user = buildUser()
        userAction.save(completion: { (complete) in
            AuthService.instance.anonymousSignUp(userCreationComplete: { (isComplete, error) in
                if complete{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRevealVC", sender: self)
                }
            }, passedUser: user)
        }, user: user)
    }
}
```

The following is in its own separate class:

```
class AuthService{
    static let instance = AuthService()

    func anonymousSignUp(userCreationComplete: @escaping(_ status: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> (), passedUser: User){
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (user, error) in
            guard let user = user else{
                userCreationComplete(false, error)
                return
            }
            var dataToPost: [String : Any]
            dataToPost = ["Gender" : passedUser.gender!, "Year of birth" : passedUser.yearOfBirth, "Salary" : passedUser.wage, "Hours worked in a day" : passedUser.hoursWorked]
            DataService.instance.createDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: dataToPost)
            userCreationComplete(true, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is probably in your xib/storyboard file—my first guess would be that something's wired to send the `setYearOfBirth:`, which fails because that method isn't defined on your class. Have you tried searching it for `setYearOfBirth:` and checked whether anything of that sort is present there?

Comment: The other possibility is that some Objective-C code could be trying to set the `yearOfBirth` property, but it's not exposed to Objective-C (the convention for getters and setters in Objective-C for a property `foo` is `-foo` and `-setFoo:`).

Comment: In the second line of `buildUser` you are setting the `yearOfBirth` property of a `User` object and the stack trace shows that it where is crashed. You need to look at your Core Data model and confirm that your `User` entity has a `yearOfBirth` attribute

Comment: @Paulw11 Not only that, but check that the `yearOfBirth` attribute is exposed to Objective-C (it should have the `@objc` attribute on it). Otherwise Core Data, which is written in Objective-C, can't see the property.

Comment: Core Data should have generated the classes correctly, but yes, they need to be checked, particularly user has created their own nsmanagedobjedt classes rather than letting Xcode do it.